# Exception in createFolder method in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am getting following error when run the below code

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script17.createFolder() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [C:/, testFolder] error at line: 38
```

Code

```
def directory = 'C:/'
def folderName = 'testFolder'
def c

def txtFileInfo = []

String a = "Today is a new day"
String b = "Tomorrow is the future"
String d = "Yesterday is the past"

txtFileInfo << a
txtFileInfo << b
txtFileInfo << d

c = createFolder(directory, folderName) //this simply creates a folder to drop the txt file in

writeToFile(c, "garbage", ".txt", txtFileInfo)




public void writeToFile(def directory, def fileName, def extension, def infoList) {
    File file = new File("$directory/$fileName$extension")

    infoList.each {
        file << ("${it}\r\n")
    }
}
```

Is there any problem with parameters in the method, Shouldn't be both string?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the "createFolder" method declared? Since a method with that signature cannot be found, either you need to declare it or import it from a library.

Comment: @silverbeak Thanks, I got you, Just one more clarification. If I want to place `writeToFile ` function some other place in order to use that method in other scripts who should I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your code to look something like this:

```
def directory = './'
def folderName = 'testFolder'
def c

def txtFileInfo = []

txtFileInfo << "Today is a new day"
txtFileInfo << "Tomorrow is the future"
txtFileInfo << "Yesterday is the past"

c = createFolder(directory, folderName)

writeToFile(c, "garbage", ".txt", txtFileInfo)


def createFolder(directory, folderName) {
    new File(directory + folderName).mkdir() 
    directory + folderName
}

public void writeToFile(String directory, String fileName, String extension, List<String> infoList) {
    File file = new File("$directory/$fileName$extension")

    infoList.each {
        file << (it + System.getProperty("line.separator"))
    }
}
```

If you want to re-use your code, put it in a class and have import that class into your file, making sure that the class is in your class path as you run your program. The way to do this is documented on the [Groovy documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Documentation).

Peace

Comment: Thanks silverbeak, really appreciated